# React Native Maps Mapview is only showing gray background on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

The map was showing fine before, this is just occuring now. I've added an API Key and did the styling, so I'm not sure what else could possibly be the cause of this. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XshJq.png)

**API KEY**
[api key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVHci.png)

**MAP COMPONENT**
[map component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY10Y.png)

**BUILD GRADLE**
[build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dj5c.png)

**ANDROID MANIFEST XML**
[android manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tygcu.png)

**GOOGLE MAPS API XML**
[google maps api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROAOl.png)

I tried adding the google maps api and even tried a new API Key, but it's still not showing.

Comment: Device or emulator you are using has internet access?

Comment: I'm using XCode Simulator

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue few days ago. In my case, I solved this by adding the below code lines to `Podfile`:

```
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/Simon-TechForm/google-maps-ios-utils.git', :branch => 'feat/support-apple-silicon'

rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I already added this on my podfile by the time i posted it here. I forgot to add it on the statement above. But my issue is now fixed. The problem was actually on the API, i just had to enable the Maps iOS SDK to make the maps show.